# How to see all window's controls. I need something like a GTK theme preview

Tags: themes, gtk, development

I'm trying to make my own GTK theme for Xubuntu.
I have no problem with customization GTK settings.
But I don't know how to see all interface's elements.
Something like this:
[Yaru theme Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy1U6.png)

Is there any app to show all elements of GTK window?
What things use theme developers usually?